# Manual repetitive conversion between file types

Tags: programming-practices, data, data-types, type-conversion

Let's say i have an interest in file conversions, but everything should be made by hand and i have multiple output formats (say: csv and excel).

Once i get contacted by a client, i have to link services and convert files. What would be the fastest way of doing this?

My guess would be to start with NodeJS and use libraries to import data into a json format. Then use the libraries to convert them to a certain file format (using libraries als).

Is there anything that would be faster / easier to create?

Comment: tell them that excel can also open csv files no problem (localization settings not withstanding)

Comment: Could you not write a function that converts your format into what your client needs? You make it sound like this is a recurring issue...

Comment: I have to provide the same functionity to multiple clients (so a custom job, but always the same flow).

So i would like to optimize the routine/workflow to do this (fastest possible)